# How to properly commit generated docs on a git repository?

Tags: git, github

I'm in a project where I need to commit generated docs on a github repository.

The problem is that docs represents a huge amount of generated lines of code that counts as written lines on github.

For now I added the folder in .gitignore

Is it a problem that docs count as lines of code? If so, is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks to any answer

Comment: What is the problem here? Why is it a problem that the generated documentation is counted in the number of lines of code. I don't think .gitignore is the right approach as now you won't see changed documentation files in the list of changed files (and probably, nit 100% sure about this though, you won't be able to commit them either). Furthermore this is not a doxygen problem but an organizational problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these docs are auto-generated somehow (e.g., javadoc, sphinx, doxygen), I wouldn't commit the documentation to git. I'd only commit the sources and the script used to generate this documentation, and add a section in the README explaining how its generated. This way any contributor who needs it can easily generate it, but you don't "pollute" your repository which huge changesets.

Comment: I agree more or less with the answer, but a bit strange, in the question it was stated " I need to commit generated docs on a github repository". It might sometimes be useful to store the resulting documentation with a release as it is not always guaranteed that after a number of years the documentation stil can be regenerated (due to e.g.  changes in OS, programs etc.).